# brew install not working - The requested URL returned error: 404

Tags: redis, homebrew

When I tried `brew install --cask another-redis-desktop-manager`, it shows below error

```
==> Downloading https://github.com/qishibo/AnotherRedisDesktopManager/releases/d
##O#- #                                                                       
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 
Error: Download failed on Cask 'another-redis-desktop-manager' with message: Download failed: https://github.com/qishibo/AnotherRedisDesktopManager/releases/download/v1.5.2/Another-Redis-Desktop-Manager-M1-arm64-1.5.2.dmg
```

I tried `brew update-reset` and `brew update` but still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/qishibo/AnotherRedisDesktopManager/releases/tag/v1.5.2

> `M1` dmg version is being repaired...

Meanwhile, you can get version 1.5.1 [here](https://github.com/qishibo/AnotherRedisDesktopManager/releases/tag/v1.5.1).